# Dynamically Add Values to UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, uibezierpath

I want to make a real time application of a line moving through time. So I want to continually add values to a Bezier Curve. To test it I am doing:

```
import UIKit

class TestView: UIView {
var arr = [CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(120, 150), CGPointMake(260, 150), CGPointMake(210, 30)]
 var control = CGPointMake(5, 5)
let path = UIBezierPath()
var count = 0

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    path.lineWidth = 3.0
    path.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(20, 40))
    path.addQuadCurveToPoint(arr[1], controlPoint: control)
    path.stroke()

    var timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: Selector("update"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

}

func update() {
    var p = arr[count]

    path.addQuadCurveToPoint(p, controlPoint: control)
    path.stroke()
    count++
}

}
```

I would clean this up, but this does not seem to work. It draws the initial line, but none of the other points are then added.

Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

A few points to get you in the right direction:

- You should not be starting your timer from drawRect(). Consider instead starting it from the view controller's viewDidAppear() method.
- drawRect() is called each time the view is told to redraw; so right now without knowing anything else about your program, I'm guessing it's only being called once.
- You should do all of your drawing in drawRect() not in update().
- Add points to the path in update(), and then call setNeedsDisplay() to actually get drawRect() called by the system, and stroke() the path in drawRect().

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! I am wondering, will this redraw the entire curve or only add the new ones? Because eventually I would like to make an animation so it looks like the curve is moving, if that makes sense. So redrawing the entire line wouldn't be the best. But i'll give that a shot!

Comment: You do redraw the whole thing in drawRect() - that's usually how it works.  However, you incrementally, via your timer's call to update() change how the path looks (in your case adding points) so it looks like an animation. In essence, each time drawRect() is called by the system (put in motion by your calls to setNeedsDisplay()), it is drawing a slightly different path.